# Count how many times each line appears in a file

Tags: text-processing

Say I have a file which contains:

```
A
A
A
B
CC
```

I want to have the output like this:

```
A 3
B 1
CC 1
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I figured it out; one of `uniq`'s options is `-c`, for "prefix lines by the number of occurrences":

```
$ uniq -c
```

Comment: Note that puts the numbers first. If you were fussy about the order, you could do: `uniq -c filename.txt | sed 's/[^0-9]*\\([0-9]\+\\) \\(.*\\)/\2 \1/'`

Comment: Also note that it only counts adjacent repeat lines.  A common idiom is `sort | uniq`

Comment: uniq also puts the count in front of the datum.  The original question would actually need something like this: sort filename | uniq -c | awk '{print $2, $1}'

Comment: In case it isn't clear from the above comments, you _must_ ensure the data is sorted first to achieve your goal. If it is not sorted, you will have repeat entries. For example, if your original file was instead `A \ A \ A \ B \ A \ CC`, the output of just `uniq -c` would show `A 3` and later show `A 1`. Sorting first, will guarantee all identical lines are grouped together

Answer (score 18):

I just came here with a similar problem. From this, I managed to put together a slightly more advanced command, which I hope is useful for others.

As Steven D said in the comments above `uniq` only counts adjacent repeat lines, so you need to sort the lines first. After that we find the unique lines then sort again so the most occurring lines are on top.

```
sort file.txt | uniq -c | sort -nr > output.txt
```

Output is redirected into the file `output.txt`. If you just want to view results on the command line, remove the redirection and change the last command to `sort -n` so that the most common line will be at the bottom, i.e. definitely still on screen.

Comment: You can replace `cat file.txt | sort` with just `sort file.txt`. :)

Comment: @mattdm: the downside of that formulation is that you can't quickly replace the `cat` with something more interesting. Since, you know, there is no `cat`.

Comment: @SamB Then write it as `< file.txt sort | uniq -c`. This is easy to edit, and still avoids the unnecessary `cat`.